# Integrated authentication works for ODBC but not JDBC for SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, authentication, jdbc, sql-server-2012

I have a Windows workstation which pulls back data from SQL Server 2012 using ODBC with Integrated Authentication with no issues.

However if we try to pull the data via JDBC, from the same workstation, towards the same db server and databsse also using Integrated Authentication we see:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot open database
>   "MC_X1" requested by the login. The login failed. 
>   ClientConnectionId:03c0f0b7-.....

The combo of Integrated Authentication and JDBC does work towards other earlier versions such as 2008 SQL Server.

Is there something that needs to be tweaked on the SQL Server 2012?
All replies appreciated

Comment: *"Integrated Authentication and JDBC does work towards other earlier versions such as 2008 SQL Server"* - Are you using the latest version of the JDBC driver for SQL Server?

Comment: Please show the connection string you use. Did you also include the sqljdbc_auth.dll (of the right bitness, and the right version matching the one of the JDBC driver version) on the path or the `java.library.path`?